# In C# is there a way to define an enum in terms of other enums?

Tags: c#, enums

A typical example is a playing Card represented by 2 enums: one for Rank and one for Suit.
One often sees ToString() return "Jack of Clubs".
But would it not be useful to also have another enum for CardName with the 52 constants in it
{Jack_of_Clubs, Queen_of_Hearts, ...}
and then be able to set/get the card as a single enum or a pair of enums.

Is there a way to conveniently do this?
Or is it a bad idea?

Comment: Why do you need an enum? Why not just a "card" class that has the rank and suit as properties? What does an enum buy you?

Comment: Note that you _could_ define 52 different constant "card" instances within the card class, but a factory may be more appropriate.

Comment: `Or is it a bad idea?` - that.

Comment: You can do that kind of thing with the Discriminated Union in F#, but you can't use that directly from C#.

Comment: If you have seen the usage of enum.ToString in code to be used to visualized it in an UI you presumably have seen code by someone ignorant to speakers of languages other than the own. For example its not called "Jack of Clubs" in my first language. So yes it feels like a bad idea on multiple levels.

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question is yes, you can define enum values using other enum values, and you can use multiple enum values to construct another enum value.

But in this case it's just not very useful. You can create enums like this:

**For emphasis, I'm directly answering the question. There's no good reason to do this, at least not in this case.**

```cs
public enum Suit
{
    Club = 16384,
    Diamond = 32768,
    Heart = 65536,
    Spade = 131072
}

public enum Rank
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 4,
    Four = 8,
    Five = 16,
    Six = 32,
    Seven = 64,
    Eight = 128,
    Nine = 256,
    Ten = 512,
    Jack = 1024,
    Queen = 2048,
    King = 4096,
    Ace = 8192
}

public enum Card
{
    OneOfClubs = Suit.Club + Rank.One,
    TwoOfClubs = Suit.Club + Rank.Two,
    // etc
    AceOfSpades = Suit.Spade + Rank.Ace
}

// And you can write a method like this.
Card GetCardFromRankAndSuit(Rank rank, Suit suit) 
    => (Card)((int)rank + (int)suit);
```

Technically you could work with this. It's just awkward. The worst part is that given a `Card` you'd have to do some unpleasant comparisons to get the suit and the rank from it.

That's why I used powers of two. It would make that comparison a little bit easier.

All of this becomes trivially easy if you just create a type instead - a class, struct, or record. Here's an example of a class:

```cs
public class Card // still using the Suit and Rank enums
{
    public Suit Suit { get; }
    public Rank Rank { get; }

    public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank)
    {
        Suit = suit;
        Rank = rank;
    }
}
```

This is much easier to work with. From here we can add custom comparers, equality comparers, or whatever we need according to the logic of the game we're creating.

Comment: I was anticipating using a class for Card just like you have. But a single card could be represented by the pair of enums (Rank, Suit) or a single enum CardName. I was unsure which was better. So I was wondering if there was a good way to have both.

Comment: I think the suit + rank enum is effectively useless. There's too much baggage and whatever you can do with it you can do more easily with a class. It becomes even clearer when you start doing things with the cards like comparing them to each other, or scenarios where in one game this card is greater than another, but in another game that logic is different.